# UINavigationController beginning in another nib file?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I've been successful in setting up a working navigation controller when it's the first thing you see when the program launches, but I've been unsuccessful when it's from a nib file other than the Main Window.

I'd like my main screen to NOT have anything to do with the navigation controller, but when you click on the settings button, you are then taken to another nib file which is the root and from there you can push new view controllers onto it, etc.

I've read countless examples, but they all focus on creating a navigation controller right from the beginning (setting the window rootViewController in AppDelegate), and I can't find anything that applies to my situation (yet it seems like it should be really simple!).

Any advice on what to do or where to look would be appreciated... thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the navigation controller on window.

1. Remove view added on window (the main view controller)
2. Add subView to window the navigation controller

For that purpose create a method in app delegate and call it from your home view controller

```
// method in app delegate looks like
-(void) switchViews {
    // mainViewCont is instance variable on app delegate of the main screen
    [homeViewCont.view removeFromSuperview];
    // navCont is instance variable on app delegate for navigation controller
    [self.window addSubview:navCont.view];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; unfortunately I'm still a little confused... Suppose that I were to create a new blank project in Xcode (using the Utility template). I'm left with MainView.xib which contains a button that takes you to FlipsideView.xib. All I'm really hoping to do is make "FlipsideView" the start of the navigation... is your answer still applicable to this? Thanks for your patience, this is one aspect of Cocoa-Touch that I just can't seem to understand...

Comment: @chris, yes you can create a button on `FlipsideView` and on the click event call the delegate method to remove FlipsideView and add navigation view to window

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to understand... I wasn't sure how involved the app delegate should have been in this process and wanted to be sure I wasn't overcomplicating the situation. Thanks again for your advice.